# macOS and iOS forgets CalDAV password

Tags: macos, ios, caldav

On my iPhone and Mac I get regularly prompted for the password of a CalDAV account (for my calendars). The password is still valid server side and just entering it again resolves the issue. Until next time....

- I checked the password in the KeyChain - it's correct and the expiry date in the KeyChain app is also **not** set
- I deleted the CalDAV account and created it again

None of this helped, any other ideas?

macOS: BigSur 11.3.1
iOS: 14.4.2

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @z-cool No the issue just disappeared. Could be either through a change on the side of my Calendar provider or an macOS update.

Comment: thank you for your reply!